# What is the verb base for 지냈어요?

Tags: grammar, vocabulary

What is the verb base for the word `지냈어요` ?
And what is the definition?

This is seen a lot in "How are you?" phrase. `잘 지냈어요?`

I want to understand the verb base.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to know the meaning of "잘 지냈어요?"
잘 means "well", and 지냈어요 is 지내다 + 었어요.(Past tense), where 지내다 means "to live". Conbined these two together, it represents the meaning of "How have you been?"